# How to hide response from dbus-send (print-reply)?

Tags: bash, shell, dbus

I have following script for playing/pausing current song on spotify. However it prints output to the terminal. When I remove `--print-reply \` part it doesn't work despite documentation shows it is optional. How to hide the response from this command?

```
dbus-send \
    --print-reply \
    --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify \
    /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 \
    org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause
```

Example output:

```
method return time=1588176965.415166 sender=:1.189 -> destination=:1.193 serial=42 reply_serial=2
```

Answer (score 1):

Redirect all output to /dev/null:

`<dbus-send etc> 2>/dev/null`

Or if you still want to see any errors, use:

`<dbus-send etc> 1>/dev/null`

Full command:

```
dbus-send \
    --print-reply \
    --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify \
    /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 \
    org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause 1>/dev/null
```

Comment: That method works but I still need to add `--print-reply` to the command what is weird. Without that part command doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know anything about dbus-send. Suggest you contact the maintainers to get the answer to your specific question. https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/dbus/dbus

Comment: @Jsowa did you ever find out why you need to use reply?

Comment: @deed02392 no, I didn't

Answer (score 1):

I was asking a similar question.  Actually there is a post from Simon McVittie, For original post see [Fix dbus-send not returning an error exit code in case an error occurred and --print-reply is not set](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105380)

The answer from Simon, which I have copy&pasted:

Question:

> Fix dbus-send not returning an error exit code in case an error occured
> and --print-reply is not set

Answer:

> This is an incompatible change to dbus-send's behaviour. Previously,
> it could be used in two modes:
>
> - no special options: send message (method call or signal), don't wait (analogous to dbus_connection_send())
> - --print-reply: send message, wait (makes no sense for signals), process reply (analogous to
>   dbus_connection_send_with_reply_and_block())
>
> This change makes the first mode impossible. In particular, if we send
> a signal rather than a method call, we are not going to get a reply,
> so we'd just block until the timeout and then fail every time.
>
> Making --print-reply the default (at least for method calls) would
> have been better, but we're about 15 years too late to design the
> dbus-send CLI, and I don't think it's a good idea to be changing it
> incompatibly now.
>
> I think "gdbus call" is a better CLI for method calls (it's missing a
> --no-wait option, but that's quite a rare thing to want in practice), and "gdbus emit" is a better CLI for signals. In particular, the
> design of the gdbus(1) CLI is in terms of operations that make sense
> in the high-level model of D-Bus that we encourage people to think in,
> whereas the design of dbus-send is down at the level of
> message-passing.
>
> One better solution than this would be to change the man page to say
> something like this:
>
> """ To call a method, always use --print-reply, unless you are
> deliberately not waiting to see whether the method succeeded.
> --print-reply is not the default for historical reasons, but it should have been.
>
> To emit a signal, use --type=signal and do not use --print-reply. """
>
> Perhaps another better solution would be "dbus-call" and "dbus-emit"
> tools that closely resemble dbus-send but with more sensible defaults
>
> - but "gdbus call" and "gdbus emit" are basically already those tools, so perhaps implementing them would be a waste of time.
>
> ::: doc/dbus-send.1.xml.in @@ +156,5 @@
>
> > - EXIT STATUS
> > - 
> > - dbus-send
> > - exits with status 0 on success and status 1 in case of errors.
> > - In the error case a related message will be printed to stderr.
>
> This is still useful documentation without the behaviour change, but
> if --print-reply isn't used, "the service sent back an error reply" is
> not an error that is (or can be) detected. It could perhaps become
> something like this:
>
> """ If the --print-reply option is used, dbus-send exits with status 0
> after a successful reply, or a nonzero status otherwise (if connecting
> to the bus fails, if it receives an error reply, or if the timeout is
> reached).
>
> If the --print-reply option is not used, dbus-send exits with status 0
> when the message has been successfully sent, or a nonzero status
> otherwise (for example if connecting to the bus fails). In this case
> dbus-send does not wait for the message to be processed, so it cannot
> report an error reply.
>
> On failure, a diagnostic message is printed to stderr. """